# Cross-compiled kernel unable to boot because of a strange module loop

Tags: architecture, linux-kernel, cross-compiling

I'm trying to prepare an optimized toolchain/OS for an embedded board with a vortexX86DX processor.

Architecture of my PC is x86_64. So I get to compile a cross compiler using cross-NG. Then compiled linux 2.6.38.8 patched with Xenomai (for rt kernel modules) using that compiler. The kernel is planned to replace current kernel. Currently default kernel of debian 6.0.4 i386 is installed on board.

The compiled kernel fails to boot with this error:

```
request_module: runaway loop modprobe binfmt-464c
```

I can'r understand what's problem with new kernel. AFAIK above error only occurs when trying to load a module used to load incompatible elfs. Though here is no incompatibility... A kernel compiled with i586 optimization (containing x86 generic code and elf emulators) should be able to load `init` of i386 architecture...

In case that matters, architecture of compiled kernel is:

```
file ./vmlinux.o 
./vmlinux.o: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

Answer (score 1):

Googled it for you: [request_module: runaway loop modprobe binfmt-464c](http://saalwaechter-notes.blogspot.com/2008/10/requestmodule-runaway-loop-modprobe.html)
It tries to load binfmt-464c, BUT modprobe itself is an ELF, so to run modprobe, it first needs binfmt-464c. Probable solution would be to include the module in the kernel build.

Comment: I know about binfmt and module infinite loop. The question is why kernel tries to load binfmt?

Comment: because kernel was configured to include this binfmt as module, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, somewhere your cross-compilation toolchain is producing other architecture binary than your i386 intended. You should check not only the kernel but 'init', 'shell' and other commands your kernel is invoking because one of those is not i386  and your kernel tries to load a module to emulate and run it.